# Resolution in IBM Worklite in Android on Different Devices

Tags: android

I started working on IBM WorkLite in Android. I made a project and put a image in body background. the pic is according to the device size but on running app the image shown in zoom mode. I am unable to understand that why this is happening

Comment: are you displaying background image in any `Relative` or `Linear` layout?

Comment: no i am not putting image in layout. But can you please guide me where i can find the layout tag in IBM Worklite Android Enviroment in Eclipse?

Comment: no no.. you don't understand my question. there is one method `android:background` in `RelativeLayout`,`LinearLayout` and other also. Are you giving drawable in that?

Comment: I am working on IBM Worklite Android Enviroment and when i create a project it gives html file for layouting. Beacuse IBM Worklite provide html and javascript developing

Comment: I am also using eclipse but it provide me `xml` files to create layouts. Sorry helpless to you as html and javascript I am not familiar with.